# C input functions mechanism

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, interrupt

How do input functions like scanf, getc, etc. work? When a program is invoked and execution reaches scanf it stops waiting for input. Does it start reading from the input buffer till it  reads code for enter key or the function implementation relies on specific system call or interrupt mechanism? I mean how the OS is involved here?

I searched online and read a few books but none explains that very well.

Comment: everything is implementation dependant. It will be different on Linux and completely different on esp32 getting data form the UART or SPI

Comment: Remember there are open-source implementations of these functions you can just read if you're so inclined. Keep in mind these are often far more complicated than you'd expect since they have to accommodate all kinds of bizarre, and sometimes broken operating systems.

Comment: Thanks, I'm already reading Plaucer's The Standard C Library. He mentions premetive functions down deep in the stdio part but that didn't answer the role of the system.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the way the stdio functions work is that they maintain a buffer (a `char` array of some size, generally with a 'head' and 'tail' pointer tracking what part of the buffer is valid/in use).  They operate on data in the buffer (input functions read from the buffer, output functions write to the buffer) and call lower-level OS functions to fill or flush the buffer when it is empty or full or when switching a FILE between input and output.

So in the case of `getc`, if the buffer is empty, it will call an OS function to get some data into the buffer, then will return the first character in the buffer (advancing the pointer, so subsequent getc calls will return subsequent characters from the buffer).  In the case of `scanf` it matches data in the buffer to the format string, consuming it (advancing the pointer) if it matches.  If there's not enough data it the buffer, it will call the OS function to get more.

Similarly, when `printf` is called, data will be written to the buffer and the OS function to actually write the data will not be called until the buffer is flushed.  You can call `setvbuf` to control the output bufferring somewhat -- you can set it to "unbuffered" (which doesn't actually eliminate the buffer, just causes the buffer to be flushed after every call) or "line buffered" (which flushes the buffer whenever a `\n` (newline) character is written.

Comment: What OS functions do they call? Could you be more specific?

Comment: @JohnKugelman It depends on the OS.  On UNIX/POSIX operating systems (such as linux) it calls `read` and `write`

Comment: " and the OS function to actually write the data will not be called until the buffer is flushed" I thought in case of printf, the function writes its output to the stdout buffer then calls the OS code to put the output buffer on the screen, then this low level code flushes stdout buffer ready for reuse?

Comment: @user3479526: "flushing the buffer" == calling the low level OS function to actually output the data to wherever it is going.